# How to get URL in the application

Tags: c#, .net

I have application that displays webpage with url something like 
https://www.test.com/checkout/reserve/DHrhrzPEC6MepeMoZinxoQD4QvAaevgx7xYDZJtX8azf0_ii_Zv2b2rpiYgToXHP

from this url program copys some images. I am trying to figure out how to get this url
into the following code i have where imageUri is that url

```
using ( WebClient webClient = new WebClient() ) 
{
   using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(imgeUri))
   {
      using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
      {
         stream.Flush();
         stream.Close();
         bitmap.Save(saveto);
      }
   }
}
```

thanks

Comment: This is kinda vague.  Are you asking how to screen scrape to pull the url out of the page so you can use it in your app?

Comment: Yes thats what I am looking for

Comment: Your code looks ok. What is not working?

Comment: yes code is fine, just dont know how to get a uri value from web page for example webpage is displaying i need to give that url each time cause it keeps changing to get the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want to screen scrape images from a webpage.  That is a very broad subject.  To get you started I suggest you look at:

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
or
[WatiN](http://watin.org/)

Or read this post.  Its a bit of a tutorial on how to go about screen scraping:

[How do you Screen Scrape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425043/how-do-you-screen-scrape)

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

This will give you the complete URL of your current page. From there you can parse string in any format you want to use in your program.